# Scanner String error

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been trying to make a simple program in eclipse indigo, but kept getting the same problem, so I made this test to see the code in the simplest way. It looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter a letter");

String answer = input.nextLine();

if(answer == "a"){

System.out.println("a equals 1");

}

else if(answer == "b"){

System.out.println("a equals 2");

}

else{

System.out.println("a is not 1 or 2");

}

input.close();
    }

}
```

My problem seems to be in the line

```
String answer = input.nextLine();
```

I found this small piece of information after a lot of testing.  If I change the code so it will use integers it will work, but it seems to have some problems with the String.  Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Try to change == into .equals(). i.e (answer == "a") into answer.equals("a").

Comment: Whenever you compare strings in Java YOU HAVE TO use equals or equalsIgnoreCase , so in this case you need to type:   if(answer.equals("a")). Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh my goodness! I can't believe that I didn't think of that! Thank you so so much!